# Get parent category in Page Meta Tag Rules

Tags: metadata, data-category

I want to take the parent category in the page meta tag rules from Business Manager.
It says in the documentation that it can be done, but there is no example and the various tests I have done do not work.
Has anyone done this?

Comment: Can you include the documentation link you are following?

Comment: Sure (search Meta Tag Rules): https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp